# Xamarin MSAL When to call AcquireTokenSilent

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

The MSAL example shows how to login, get an access token, and use that token to call an API. What it doesn't show is how to call a 2nd, 3rd, etc. API call. Are you supposed to cache your access token and use it for every API call until it expires or call `AquireTokenSilent` before making EVERY API call? MSAL doesn't return a refresh token so I have no way to refresh it myself. I have access tokens configured to expire after an hour. I believe I need to refresh the token if the user uses the app for longer than an hour.

I tried calling it before every API call but it's slow and it looks like it's getting a new token every time. It can take anywhere from 200 to 800ms. I also created a `DelegatingHandler` for `HttpClient`, which looks for 401 responses and calls `AcquireTokenSilent` to refresh the tokens. The problem is the app hangs when I make this call from within the `DelegatingHandler`. The call never returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I filed a bug in Github for this because MSAL is supposed to return the cached token instead of refreshing the token every time. This was not happening because I was using `user_impersonate` scope. Microsoft put in a bug fix for this. In the mean time, if you're having this issue and the bug fix hasn't been released yet, remove the `user_impersonate` scope and it should work properly. I have removed the code I was using to cache the token myself.

Original:
I figured out the problem. I believe the correct path is to cache the token and use it for subsequent calls. Using a `DelegatingHandler` to watch for 401 responses and then calling `AcquireTokenSilent` works. I had a bug which caused the app to hang. This seems like a good approach.

Comment: Hmm, Silent really shouldn't be getting a new token each time as long as its cache works... Sounds like an issue with MSAL cache?

Comment: @juunas Yes, it is returning new tokens every time. I just tested it by calling it 4 times in a row.

Comment: Did you ever get around this? Also, do you know if there's any way to mimic the (seemingly) behavior of AWS Amplify which seems to integrate within the app (say ReactJS native) where it doesn't redirect you but internally seems to do the MFA work, whereas with MSAL it always does the browser flow? Is that just a limitation/difference between MSAL and AWS's APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you figured it out what the problem was I want to make sure you are following the correct pattern.

The following code is from this link ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/xamarin?tutorial-step=3#get-user-details)):

```
private async Task InitializeGraphClientAsync()
{
    var currentAccounts = await PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
    try
    {
        if (currentAccounts.Count() > 0)
        {
            // Initialize Graph client
            GraphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    var result = await PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, currentAccounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                }));

            await GetUserInfo();

            IsSignedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsSignedIn = false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(
            $"Failed to initialized graph client. Accounts in the msal cache: {currentAccounts.Count()}. See exception message for details: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

The important part is when they create a new Graph client. They add a delegate that will be executed with every request to aqcuire and add a token to the request header. If the token is almost expired then this `AcquireTokenSilent` method will first get a new token using the `Refresh token` and then returning it to this method.

If you are using your own API and also need this token you could create your own delegate using the same logic. With every request you execute a method/delegate that adds the (cached or new) token to your request.

Do not store the token yourself, The microsoft library is made for this and stores them in a secure way.

Comment: Every time I call `AcquireTokensSilent` it refreshes the tokens, even if they don't need to be. If my approach is not the recommended one, it's one I'm going to have to use due to this bug.